# react-native-plaid-link-sdk on Mac with M1 chip

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, plaid

We have a React Native app. If I follow these steps on a Mac with an Intel chip works fine, but the same steps with the M1 chip throw an error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. add *pod 'Plaid'* at the Podfile (I tried with version 2.2, 2.0 and without it)
2. run *pod install*

[image]

I tried reinstalling ffi and cocoapods, but with no luck.

Comment: This looks like something Plaid would probably need to fix rather than something the SO community can help with -- if you haven't already filed a support ticket with Plaid, can you try doing that?